# Inequality for divisor sigma $\sigma_{\nu}(n)$ function.

Tags: number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, divisor-counting-function

The divisor sigma function is defined as
$$
\sigma_{\nu}(n):=\sum_{d|n}d^{\nu}\textrm{, }n\in\textbf{N}
$$
It is known that under Riemann's hypothesis it holds the following inequality due to Ramanujan and Robin see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)
$$
\sigma_1(n)<e^{\gamma}n\log\log n\textrm{, }n>5040\tag 1
$$
($\gamma$ is Euler-constant, $0.5772156649...$)The opposite is also true: (1) implies Riemann's hypothesis.

My question is: Are there similar inequalities in the literature for $\sigma_{\nu}(n)$, for other values of $\nu=2,3,\ldots$?

With the word similar I mean inequalities of the form
$$
\sigma_{\nu}(n)<C_{\nu}n^{\nu}\log\log n\textrm{, }\forall n>n_0,
$$
where $C_{\nu}$ some known constants (I need the values of these constants also).

My starting point is equation
$$
9d^2(k^2+4d)=n^2\textrm{, }(n,k,d)\in\textbf{Z}^3.\tag 2
$$
When $n$ is around $\sigma_1(n)\approx e^{\gamma}n\log\log n$ i.e. when $n$ is such that $0,85<\frac{\sigma(n)}{e^{\gamma}n\log\log n}<1$, then we have a ''jump'' in the number of solutions $L=L(n)$ of (2) from (say) $L$ to $L+6$. For example $n=10080$, $L=18$; $n=19440$, $L=24$; $n=55440$, $L=30$; $n=443520$, $L=36$; $\ldots$.

Equation (2) is equivalent (have the same number of solutions) to
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3=n\textrm{, }x+y+z=0
$$
For the case
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3=n\textrm{, }x+y+z=t,
$$
we have the general equation
$$
\left(\frac{n-t^3}{3d}+2t\right)^2-4d=k^2,
$$
which I suspect to have solutions $n$ around $\sigma_{\nu}(n)\approx C_{\nu}n^{\nu}\log\log n$, $\nu=\nu(t)$.

Comment: For $\nu > 1$ we have (for $n > 1$, the first inequality would be an equality for $n = 1$) $$n^{\nu} < \sigma_{\nu}(n) < n^{\nu}\cdot \zeta(\nu)\,,$$ and $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma_{\nu}(n)}{n^{\nu}} = 1\,, \qquad \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma_{\nu}(n)}{n^{\nu}} = \zeta(\nu)\,.$$ This independently from the distribution of zeros of $\zeta$.

Comment: @DanielFischer. So for $\nu>1$ there is no other term. Can you give me references?

Comment: I don't know about references. If you write the divisors of $n$ in the form $\frac{n}{d}$ it is straightforward, $$\sigma_{\nu}(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \biggl(\frac{n}{d}\biggr)^{\nu} = n^{\nu} \sum_{d \mid n} \frac{1}{d^{\nu}}\,.$$ It's clear that the last sum is strictly (for $n > 1$) between $1$ and $\zeta(\nu)$. For $n$ a large prime the sum is _very_ close to $1$, and if $n$ is a common multiple of $1, 2, \dotsc, k$ for large $k$, then the sum is close to $\zeta(\nu)$.

Comment: In Tom's Apostol book "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory", chapter 13, there is an exercise that mentions $\sigma_{\nu}(n)=o(n^{\nu+\delta})$, $\forall \delta>0$, $n\rightarrow+\infty$.Im looking for a better estimate than T. Apostol's. If $\nu^{\delta}$ is replaced with some other function (for example $\log n$ or $\log\log n$) then what we can tell about?

Comment: For $\nu > 1$, or more generally $\operatorname{Re} \nu > 1$, we have $\sigma_{\nu}(n)\asymp n^{\nu}$ as you can see above. So then every function with $f(n)\to +\infty$ works in $\sigma_{\nu}(n)=o\bigl(n\cdot f(n)\bigr)$. But since then we know something better it's rather pointless. For $\nu = 1$ we know $\sigma_1(n) = O(n\log\log n)$ (and also $\Omega(n\log \log n)$). Again, it's pointless to take a faster growing $f$ to say $\sigma_1(n) = o\bigl(n\cdot f(n)\bigr)$. For $\nu = 1+it$ with $t \neq 0$ we easily have $O(n\log \log n)$, and I think proving $o(n\log\log n)$ shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: The inequality $n^{\nu}<\sigma_{\nu}(n)<\zeta(\nu)n^{\nu}$, does not hold in general. For every $\nu>1$, there exists subsequence $n=n_m\in\textbf{N}$ such that $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{d|n_m}d^{-\nu}=+\infty$. Im almost sure about this.

Comment: No, since $1 \mid n$ and $d \mid n \implies d \leqslant n$ we have $$1 \leqslant \sum_{d \mid n} d^{-\nu} \leqslant \sum_{d = 1}^{n} d^{-\nu} < \sum_{d = 1}^{\infty} d^{-\nu} = \zeta(\nu)$$ for $\nu > 1$, and the first inequality is also strict for $n > 1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112718/discussion-between-nikos-bagis-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: Nikos, you should get Ramanujan's original article (about 1915, I forget). The unpublished part was published, with annotation, by Nicolas and Robin.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Louis_Nicolas   and   http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/    and  http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html  and finally  http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/ramanujanNR.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy. Thanks.

Comment: @WillJagy.Ohh Wow whats a story!!! Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: You might be interested in these notes of mine, which could answer your question: https://ia600501.us.archive.org/12/items/some_inequalities_similar_to_lagarias_inequality/some_inequalities_similar_to_lagarias_inequality.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here are inequalities for $-v=-1,0,1,2,3,\cdots$ which I think is what you were asking for:

Let $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n{1/k}$ be the $n$-th harmonic number. Let $\sigma_r(n) = \sum_{d|n} d^r$ be a sum of divisors of $n$. Let
$U_1(n) := H_n + \exp(H_n)\log(H_n)$ and for $s=0,1,2,3\cdots$ and let
\begin{equation}\label{eq2} U_{-s}(n) := \frac{1}{n}(U_{-s+1}(n) + \sum_{d < n, d|n} \sigma_{-s+1}(d) \phi(\frac{n}{d})) \end{equation}
We show in the following that for all $s=-1,0,1,2,\cdots$ we have

\begin{equation}\label{eq3}\sigma_{-s}(n) \le U_{-s}(n) \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \iff \text{ Riemann Hypothesis is true }\end{equation}

Disclaimer: These notes were written by me:

https://ia600501.us.archive.org/12/items/some_inequalities_similar_to_lagarias_inequality/some_inequalities_similar_to_lagarias_inequality.pdf